# when export to pdf i got extra one empty page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, tppdf

I am saving images into pdf document

let suppose I have 3 images and add them to the document it should show 3 pages. but what's happing is this I am getting 4 pages with the first page empty.I am using TPPDF pod for this

**TPPDF Environment**
*TPPDF version: 2.3.5
Xcode version: 13.0
Swift version: 4 or above*

**Demo Code / Project**

```
let document = PDFDocument(format: .a4)
document.add(.footerLeft, textObject: PDFSimpleText(text: "Generated from Pdf Scanner"))
for eachImage in images{
    let imageElement = PDFImage(image: eachImage)
    imageElement.sizeFit = .height
    document.add(.contentCenter ,image: imageElement)              
 }
let generator = PDFGenerator(document: document)
let pdfUrl = (try? generator.generateURL(filename: "Example.pdf"))!
```

Comment: I am adding multiple images to the PDF. Loop is for that. And i need a Footer In Every Page

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad can you show your full code like also images array?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya I'll update the Question

Comment: @KishanBhatiya because calling document.add(.footerLeft, ...) once will add the footer on all pages.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad can you try fitting each image to a small artificial size (e.g. 100x100) to rule out overflows?

Comment: @squall3d i don't have any issue with that

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad can you please update the question with your full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of your images is too large, but without access to the images I can't tell for sure.  I created three images with SF Symbols and played with resizing the images.  I can create the problem by setting the images too large.

```
    let images = [NSImage(systemSymbolName: "xmark", accessibilityDescription: "xmark")!,
    NSImage(systemSymbolName: "pencil.slash", accessibilityDescription: "pencil")!,
    NSImage(systemSymbolName: "pencil.and.outline", accessibilityDescription: "pencil")!]
    let document = PDFDocument(format: .a4)
    document.add(.footerLeft, textObject: PDFSimpleText(text: "Generated from Pdf Scanner"))
    for eachImage in images {
//      eachImage.size = NSSize(width: 400, height: 380)
//      above works
        eachImage.size = NSSize(width: 790, height: 760)
        let imageElement = PDFImage(image: eachImage)
        imageElement.sizeFit = .height
        document.add(.contentCenter ,image: imageElement)
    }
    
    let generator = PDFGenerator(document: document)
    generator.debug = true
    let pdfUrl = (try? generator.generateURL(filename: "Example.pdf"))!
    print("pdf location: \(pdfUrl)")
```

Note:  `generator.debug = true` might be useful.

Comment: i am clicking all the images from the camera but i am gonna check if its the height if the image issue.

Comment: Brother Not Working. Same problem

Comment: In addition to height, width can cause an overflow.  Try writing the image size to the console log:  `print("size: \(imageElement.size)")` just before adding to the document.